# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, webtorrent

So here is a simple function that uses webtorrent:

```
addTorrent (opts) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      console.log('in try catch');
      let torrent = wtClient.add(opts.source, (torrent) => {
        console.log('client.add callback');
        var nled = normalize(torrent);
        console.log('normalized ', torrent.infoHash);
        resolve(nled);
      });
      console.log('after add')
      torrent.on('download', (chunkSize) => {
        console.log(chunkSize);
        this.emit('torrent:' + torrent.infoHash + ':download', chunkSize);
      });
      console.log('after on');
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(pe.render(err));
      process.exit(1);
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
```

And to call it:

```
var MAGNET_URI = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:09e37f73e51f403bb543517f0d0a2e1283d61eb0&dn=archlinux-2015.12.01-dual.iso&tr=udp://tracker.archlinux.org:6969&tr=http://tracker.archlinux.org:6969/announce';
socketClient.connect().then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to webtorrent');
    return socketClient.status();
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return socketClient.addTorrent({source: MAGNET_URI});
}).then((data) => {
    console.log('Added torrent:', data);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And here is the output:

```
root@ubuntu-512mb-lon1-01:~/pTorrent# DEBUG=webtorrent,ut_metadata,dht,tracker,ut_pex npm start

> pTorrent@0.0.2 start /root/pTorrent
> node server.js --env=dev

  webtorrent new webtorrent (peerId 2d5757303036332d323330643939666634313638, nodeId c59e8b616c66cf97437fd69f4ae037d00709b83b) +0ms
Listening at localhost:8080
Opening your system browser...
Client connected...
WEBPACK STUFF

Client connected...
in try catch
  webtorrent add +42s
after add
after on
client.add callback
normalized  09e37f73e51f403bb543517f0d0a2e1283d61eb0
error occured for addTorrent
  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

  - Torrent.hasOwnProperty

  - index.js:47 _hasBinary
    [pTorrent]/[has-binary-data]/index.js:47:17

  - index.js:37 _hasBinary
    [pTorrent]/[has-binary-data]/index.js:37:15

  - index.js:47 _hasBinary
    [pTorrent]/[has-binary-data]/index.js:47:40

  - index.js:47 _hasBinary
    [pTorrent]/[has-binary-data]/index.js:47:40

  - index.js:37 _hasBinary
    [pTorrent]/[has-binary-data]/index.js:37:15

  - index.js:47 _hasBinary
    [pTorrent]/[has-binary-data]/index.js:47:40

  - index.js:47 _hasBinary
    [pTorrent]/[has-binary-data]/index.js:47:40

  - index.js:37 _hasBinary
    [pTorrent]/[has-binary-data]/index.js:37:15

  - index.js:47 _hasBinary
    [pTorrent]/[has-binary-data]/index.js:47:40


16384
16384
16384
16384
```

And `16384` repeats until it runs out of memory.

**EDIT:** After a bit research, it turned out that 16384 was the bytes received every x at a very high rate (since i'm on a VPS). My torrent would successfully be downloaded in a matter of secs (found it in /tmp/webtorrent/ :D)

However that does not solve the RangeError which is caused by the `resolve();` line

Answer (score 0):

After a bit research, it turned out that 16384 was the bytes received every x at a very high rate (since i'm on a VPS). My torrent would successfully be downloaded in a matter of secs (found it in `/tmp/webtorrent/` :D)

The RangeError was caused by my normalize function which would leave the objects and make it too large.